# How would I go about calling in to run another class from a separate package?

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm currently writing an inventory system program and I need some help with it. I've got depots and Products, products being a child of the depots. I have been trying so where I select a depot through an if statement and a GUI system if for example 1 is entered, run the javascript file that pulls up a similar menu system for the products instead. The file that needs to be run is in a separate package from the file that I wish to call it from. How would I go about this? I have tried extensively but have failed

```
public void showAll() {
    int IID = 0;
    System.out.println("--All depots--");
    System.out.println("ID\tName\t\tTotal Products");
    for (int i = 0; i < this.pm.count(); i++) {
        Depot p = this.pm.getDepot(i);
        System.out.println(p.getId() + "\t" + p.getName()+"\t");
    }
    int num = -1;
    while(num < 0)
    {
    System.out.println("Select:\n(1): Depot 1\n(2): Depot 2\n(0): Exit");
    num = readInt(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    if (num == 1) {
        // run the file productconsole for the first depot
    }
    else if (num ==2) {
        // run the file productconsole2 for the second depot
    }

}
```

I want is so where the comments are places, I am able to run the product console java file (ProductConsole1 & ProductConsole2 Respectively).

Thankyou Kindly :D

Comment: @AdamMatthews, what do you mean by separate package? Do you mean a Java class from another package?

Comment: @Sometowngeek I mean that each class file is in its own package. I'm new to java so I wasn't sure whether it affected the outcome or not. I'm running eclipse IDE

Comment: @AdamMatthews, If my answer is not the one you're looking for, let me know. I want to make sure I understand your plight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Given the case of the project looking like this

[image: Java project]

To use a class from a different package, you need to make sure to import the package and the class. The code would look like this:

---

#### ThisClass.java

```
package bar;
import java.util.Scanner;

import foo.pkg.ThatClass;

public class ThisClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            String answer = "";
            
            System.out.print("Please enter Y or N: ");
            answer = in.next();
            
            if (answer.toUpperCase().equals("Y"))
                // Call another class' main function.
                ThatClass.main(null);
            else {
                System.out.println("You entered the wrong value.");
            }
                
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

#### ThatClass.java

```
package foo.pkg;

public class ThatClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ThatClass is here!");
    }
}
```

---

#### Result:

> Please enter Y or N: Y
>
> ThatClass is here!

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much. Now how would I be able to launch that script now it is imported. For example: If (Userinput = 1) { thatClass(); }. Or something like that

Comment: @AdamMatthews I'm not sure I follow. What is "that script"? Is it a Java file or what?

Comment: as you've helped me above import the scrip form another package. How will I use that newly imported script to actually run? Would I just use thatClass();.

Comment: Basically halfway through my program, if an if the statement is true, run the other class.

Comment: I don't think you can run more than one class at a time. To **run** a class, the class must have a main function and in each project, there can only be one main function. The main function is fired when the program is run. Typically other classes would have specific functions that you need. I'll update my answer to give some examples.

Comment: @AdamMathews Updated... Let me know if this helps or if you need more clarification.

Comment: This definitely helps :D. It's just what I'm wanting to do is run another class. What sort of code should I be using exactly? For example from above in psuedocode:::::       If(USER_INPUT==1) {Run Sanitiser.java;}

Comment: Derp.... I just found out I was wrong. You can have more than one java file that has main(String[] args) in a project. You just need to specify which class you want to run from. I'll update my answer.